# Bitcoin Base 58 wif format Private Key recovery Front 5 character are missing

Tags: address, private-key, private-key-import, recover-private-key

I lost my private key front 5 character can i gain back my private key my address is 1PfNh5fRcE9JKDmicD2Rh3pexGwce1LqyU  i didn't have any backup. If any one help me to get my private key back i will give you good Reward.

Comment: Check out my repo https://github.com/salian/btc-incomplete-key
Recovering 5 characters is doable.

Answer (score 2):

A private key in WIF format has a checksum of 4 bytes, and with that checksum you can check every possible key for a valid checksum.

I made a program do recover missing characters in a private key. Please note it is not fast because it is written in js, but it works and should be sufficient for 5 missing character.

https://github.com/antonilol/btc_stuff/blob/master/priv_key_recovery.js

with 6 or more chracters there can be multiple possible private keys. If that's the case you can remove `process.exit(0);` on line 22 (it exits the program after finding a key)

Answer (score 0):

if you really have the rest of the Private key, yes it is possible to recover it, there are many software out there that can help you.

Google something like "recover missing characters in Private key", then look for a result on Github links, read the instructions of that software, turn your internet off when using it, and be really really careful.